# oracle select query, build columns dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle

I am returning the primary key through a query like:

```
SELECT b.column_name
FROM all_constraints a, all_cons_columns b
WHERE a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
AND a.table_name = 'tableX';
AND a.constraint_type = 'P'
```

... and the query returns 3 rows, e.g.
A
B
C

Now I want to create a query that nested in the above query to create another query like:

```
SELECT A, B, C 
FROM tableY
```

So the A, B, C part needs to be replaced by a query.  Any ideas?
I am using Oracle 11G.

Comment: For a dynamic Oracle query you'll need [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm).

Comment: Straight forwad SQL can't handle a dynamically changing number of columns.  Which means that you'll need to write code (in SQL or another language) that reads your metadata data tables to write another SQL statement with the columns you want.  Then execute that dynamically written SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ed and Mat suggested, this is almost certainly best done through `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or some PL/SQL block that outputs a query.

For those rare cases when this must be done in a single SQL statement, try my open source project [Method4](https://github.com/jonheller1/method4).  It lets you run a query generated by a query.  It's powerful, but more confusing, slower, and buggier than a regular SQL statement.

```
--Sample schema:
drop table tablex;
create table tableX(A number, B number, C number, D varchar2(10),
    constraint tableX_pk primary key (A,B,C));
insert into tableX values (1,2,3,'4');

--Query the primary key columns of a table.
select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
    q'[
        --Query that returns a query.
        SELECT
            'select '||listagg(b.column_name,',') within group (order by column_name)||
            ' from '||a.table_name v_sql
        FROM all_constraints a, all_cons_columns b
        WHERE a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
            AND a.table_name = 'TABLEX'
            AND a.constraint_type = 'P'
        GROUP BY a.table_name
    ]'
));

--Results:
A   B   C
-   -   -
1   2   3
```

Comment: Thanks I got what I need from your answer.